# Add platform license to computer

Tags: xamarin, subscription

I've xamarin license for Android and iOS.

In my account, i can see computers, and in my computer there is Android platform activated.

But I have iOS license too. How do I add that license to the computer?

My subscriptions are Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS, both are linked to my account. In Xamarin Studio I'm connected with that account, but I can see only android templates.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin.Studio on Windows does not support iOS projects. You need to use Visual Studio for that.

Answer (score 2):

As was already said, Xamarin Studio on Windows does not support iOS projects. However, if you have an Indie license, you won't be able to connect from Visual Studio to the Mac build machine. With the Xamarin licensing system, you can only use a Business or Enterprise license to develop for iOS using Visual Studio on Windows.

If you don't have a Business or Enterprise license, you can look into updating to the newest Xamarin release, which has changed the licensing terms so everyone is able to use Xamarin for free! If you don't have a MSDN license, you can use Visual Studio Community 2015 (which comes with Xamarin) to build for iOS. See [this blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/) for more on that announcement.

And in case you need it, for more information on how to set up your environment on Windows and connect from Visual Studio to the Mac build machine, see [the following](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/).

Comment: Many thanks.

I'm a student and I managed to have both android and iOS license.

After updating Visual Studio I can see iOS templates.

By the way, the link is really usefull, thanks again.